# What's the best way to compare and combine the DateTime stamp as calculated property?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The below script was created to get the actual most recent AD LastLogon from all domain controllers.
I need to get the oldest date or the most recent entry from the *LastLogon* attribute.

However, the results are different and it is quite confusing like below:
[image]

This is the script I've come up so far:

```
function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName) {
    $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter { Name -like "*" }
    $time = 0
    foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
        Write-Host "Processing $($userName) ... $($dc.HostName) [$($(Resolve-DnsName -Name $dc.hostname).IPaddress)]" -ForegroundColor Green
        $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon
        if ($user.LastLogon -gt $time) {
            $time = $user.LastLogon
        }
    }
    $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
    Write-Host "`n" $username "last logged on at:" $dt " `n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    return $dt
}

$filter = { Enabled -eq $True}
$properties = 'Name', 'canonicalName', 'whenCreated', 'displayName', 'lastlogondate', 'lastlogon'
$Name = 'Enterprise.Admins'

Get-ADUser $Name -Properties $properties |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName,
                            SamAccountName,
                            UserPrincipalName,
                            WhenCreated,
                            @{ n = 'Most Recent Logon'; e = { Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $_.SamaccountName } },
                            @{ n = 'Real Last Logon'; e = { $sam = $_.SamaccountName; [datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADDomainController -Filter { Name -like "*" } | ForEach { Write-Host "Server: $($_.Name) - DisplayName: $($sam)" -ForegroundColor Yellow ; Get-ADUser $sam -Properties $properties -Server $_.Name | Select-Object LastLogon} | Measure-Object -Property LastLogon -Maximum).Maximum) } },
                            LastLogonDate | Out-GridView
```

How can we combine the above three columns **Real Last Logon**, **Most Recent Logon** and **LastLogonDate** into one proper column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for ...

> ***"How can we combine the above three columns Real Last Logon, Most Recent Logon and LastLogonDate into one proper column?"***

I don't have an ADDS environment handy to use that, so just using the filesystem and random text stuff.

You can use one calculated property for all three dates. Say, @{Name = 'LogOnDates';Expression {' all your date info here'}}, but this then will show up as a single line representation in that single column.

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\*.txt' | 
Select-Object -First 1 | 
Select-Object -Property FullName, 
@{
    Name = 'DateDetails'
    Expression = {@(
                        $PSItem.CreationTime, 
                        $PSItem.LastAccessTime, 
                        $PSItem.LastWriteTime
                   )
                  }
} | Out-Gridview
```

Yet, what it sounds like what you are after is to have those heading as well, and that is not something OGV has the ability to do. You'd have to define your own custom version of OGV or doing stuff like this:

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\*.txt' | 
Select-Object -First 1 | 
Select-Object -Property FullName, 
@{
    Name = 'DateDetails'
    Expression = {@(
                        [PSCUstomObject]@{
                            CreationTime   = $PSItem.CreationTime
                            LastAccessTime = $PSItem.LastAccessTime
                            LastWriteTime  = $PSItem.LastWriteTime
                        }
                   )
                  }
} | Out-Gridview
```

Or getting more creative with approaches like this:

```
$col = @(

    (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'id'='01';'name'='a';'items'=@('the first item','the second item', 'the third item')}),
    (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'id'='02';'name'='b';'items'=@('the first item','the second item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item', 'the third item')}),
    (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'id'='03';'name'='c';'items'=@('the first item','the second item', 'the third item')})
    )

$col | Select -p id,@{E={$_.items -join "`n"};L="Items"},name | Out-GridView
```

Or trick like this:

```
 ('[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]' | 
ConvertFrom-Json) | 
Out-GridView
```

Or

```
$List = @()
$List += [pscustomobject]@{
 Column1 = "abc"
 Column2 = "cde"
 Column3 = "fgd"
}
$List += [pscustomobject]@{
 Column1 = "cab"
 Column2 = "dre"
 Column3 = "fde"
}
$List | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, I never knew about that. Thanks postanote

Comment: No worries. I regularly work with trying to get folks to leverage OGV, Show-Command, Msgbox, and HTML to avoid writing full UX/UI WinForm/WPF solutions.  Using those three, you can really get creative and never write any form code. There are several ways to get OGV to do some really interesting tricks, vs just the default stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your goal is to extract three datetime values, compare them with each other, and return the recent-most one. In this case, you could pass all variables to Measure-Object like so:

```
(($MostRecentLogon,$RealLastLogon,$LastLogonDate) | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
```

This will compare all three dates and output the highest value (i.e., the most recent date).

Comment: that is true, but the OP asked: 'I need to get the oldest date or the most recent entry from the LastLogon attribute.' So, though the OP is showing 3 dates, the OP is asking for one, with this statement, then all three in the latter part of the post, that I proposed an answer. So the OP really needs to define better what they are after. So, is the OP saying, they want all three in one column, sorted, or just all 3 in a column or just one or the other in that column. Meaning that 'oldest date or the most recent ', part.

Comment: For sure, I saw that you posted an answer at the same time as I did, OP is definitely not  clear with what they need. Another interpretation is that since they say "I need to get the oldest date or the most recent entry from the LastLogon attribute." it could be get either the oldest date, OR just get the LastLogon attribute, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Roger that.  The OP could obviously, combine what we provided, then use Sort-Object or Sort-Object -Descending is a conditional check to put one or the other on top, while listing all three.